# NIVO Slider Round Corner Problem

Tags: slider

Please visit [my site](http://www.erikrp.com/onepack/).

If you look at my slider you will find the first slide is perfect, but all other slides have white corners ONLY on the bottom of the images.

I can't figure this out!  I solved the problem initially by giving the slices round corners, but then the transition effect would leave the image looking cut up with round corner slices.

Can anyone make suggestions here? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: The creator of the NIVO slider is useless with this problem.  And don't tell me about PNG's.  It has nothing to do with PNG's.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your problem on the site. Could you explain exactly where you are seeing it (possibly screenshot), plus in which browser?

Comment: @sleske: look closely at the bottom-left and bottom-right corners of the large horizontal slideshow in the upper-third of the page. Especially when the slide transitions, I see (in Chrome 6) a small amount of white in the corners.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, now I see it as well (Firefox 4.0b7). Is is *very* subtle, would never have seen it without looking for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in elements with class attribute set to "nivo-slice". Probably, this snippet will fix the problem:

```
.nivo-slice { 
    -moz-border-radius: 9px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px; 
    border-radius: 9px; 
    ... 
}
```

Comment: This really messes up the slideshow images, I get several corners appearing through the top of each image.

Comment: This solution is wrong. You do not understand what Nivo Slider does.

Answer (score 5):

This modified Nivo Slider script is what you might be looking for:
http://web3o.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-nivo-slider-with-css3-round.html

Answer (score 2):

```
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px;     
}
```

This might help. Works for me!

Comment: This one actually helped. You only need to add this css and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, it does require a bit of compromise with NivoSlider though.  The only way I could get it to work is to make it so there is only 1 slice in the slider, so depending on your perspective that may be workable or not.

Then you just apply border-radius to nivo-slice and the slider wrapper elements and you should be in business. This did work with CSS3PIE too, so I was able to get cross browser compatibility with it.